# Accordian div Pops up on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to use accordian to create my page.
It works fine when I click the button but the only problem is that the div comes open on page load and I want it to be closed. It should only open when the button is clicked.

```
<a href="" class="accordion">Click here</a>
 <div class="panel" id="AccordionDiv">
            <div class="store">
                <div class="store-row">

                    <div class="cells store-logo text-center">
                        <img src="@strStaticWebsiteUrl@(objOfferPrice.StoreImage)" alt="" />
                    </div>

                    @if (objOfferPrice.Price < objOfferPrice.UrlPrice)
                    {
                        <div class="cells text-center">
                            <div class="product-price offer-price">Rs. @String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:0,0}", objOfferPrice.Price)<sup>*</sup></div>
                            <p class="real-price">Price: @objOfferPrice.UrlPrice</p>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
           </div>
```

This is html code and below is the Script code.

```
            <script>
                var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
                    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {

                        this.classList.toggle("active");
                        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
                        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
                            panel.style.display = "none";
                        } else {
                            panel.style.display = "block";
                        }
                    });
                        }
            </script>
```

Comment: Why have you tagged JQuery and AngularJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `style="display:none"` to your pannel div

**Change**

```
 <div class="panel" id="AccordionDiv">
```

**To**

```
 <div class="panel" id="AccordionDiv" style="display:none">
```

[Wokring demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r61cp52c/)

Comment: Sir  is there a way to make this div slde up and down slowly? or i could say toggle?

Answer (score 0):

With the code you have, set an inline style="display:none" so the accordion will be closed by default. The recommended way would be to have classes as open/close and toggle between them rather than having styles inlined.

Comment: Sir  is there a way to make this div slde up and down slowly? or i could say toggle?

Answer (score 0):

Hide it initially and show it when button click fires

```
<div class="panel" id="AccordionDiv" style="display:none";>


     <script>
      window.onload = function(){
            var acc = document.getElementByClassName("accordion");
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
                acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {

             document.getElementById("AccordionDiv").style.display="block";
                    this.classList.toggle("active");
                    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
                    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
                        panel.style.display = "none";
                    } else {
                        panel.style.display = "block";
                    }
                });
                    }}
        </script>
```